# Prerequisites to reading *Convergence of Probability Measures* by Patrick Billingsley.

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, asymptotics, book-recommendation

I want to improve myself in asymptotic theory regarding the realm of probability.

I tried reading *Convergence of Probability Measures* by Patrick Billingsley but right off the bat the De Moivre-Laplace limit theorem is mentioned. I have yet to prove this theorem.

So I was wondering if there was a text recommended to read before approaching *Convergence of Probability Measures* by Patrick Billingsley?

Comment: All you need is a good understanding of measure-theoretic probability theory. You can get this from Billingsley's other classic book: Probability and Measure. (In order to read that book, you'll need a basic understanding of (undergraduate) real analysis.) The answer below seems like overkill. Billingsley does a good job of introducing concepts from functional analysis when necessary and delevops them in his book, so the required background is modest.

Answer (score 4):

A course on graduate real analysis (e.g. Rudin Complex and Real analysis) and graduate probability (e.g. Billingsley's other book probability and measure) should be pretty solid. Actually probability and measure alone might be just good enough assuming some preparation on general topology, various "spaces" (Hilbert, Lp space in particular), Fourier analysis etc. A course on functional analysis (e.g. Rudin) is recommended but not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Rick Durrett's Probability: Theory and Examples, as another answer pointed out, Billingsley's other book Probability and measure is also great but the approach in the book is somewhat different(it starts with introduction to normal number).